# Preserving order when copying elements using Deliverance / XPath

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, deliverance

How would I, using [Deliverance](http://deliverance.openplans.org/configuration.html) & XPath (or CSS) selectors, select and copy list items .one and .three from each list below, but display them in the order of their parent list?

```
<ul id="a-wrapper">
   <li class="one"></li>
   <li class="two"></li>
   <li class="three"></li>
   <li class="four"></li>
</li>

<ul id="b-wrapper">
   <li class="one"></li>
   <li class="two"></li>
   <li class="three"></li>
   <li class="four"></li>
</ul>

    c,d,e,f,g etc....
```

The catch is it needs to use a href rule, eg: `<prepend href="/blah/deblah" content="#x" theme="#y" />`

Using the following just lists all the .one elements, then all the .three elements.

```
<prepend href="/blah/deblah" content=".one" theme="#y" />
<prepend href="/blah/deblah" content=".three" theme="#y" />
```

Comment: This is not an XPath question at all. Please edit and remove the xpath tag.

Comment: Accepted answer was XPath solution. Removal of XPath tag reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but to grab all at once in source order use this XPATH:

```
//ul[@id='a-wrapper' or @id='b-wrapper']/li[@class='one' or @class='three']
```